# preprareForSegue:sender: is never called on a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have simple storyboard project, with a UITableViewController and a detail VC. The Table View Controller has a custom class which is the delegate and data source of the table.

I'm creating the cells with the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    // Configure the cell...


    return cell;
}
```

The definition the tableview in the storyboard is as follows:

[image]

It displays correctly, however, when I click on a cell, nothing happens and prepareforSegue:sender: is never called.

In the storyboard, the tableview cell is connected to the detail VC:

[image]

I already check for similar questions, but nothing seems to apply to my case. The custom class of the tableview is set and all the delegate and data source wiring seems to be ok.

I'm quite new to storyboards, so I fear the error must be in the configuration of it. If I implement didSelectRow... I can get the system to work as expected, but I'd like to do it with segues.

Comment: Tell me that you have connect your UITableViewController with the detail View using a push segue..

Comment: And where should the segue called? `performForSegue:` in code ? On the Storyboard, where is it connected?

Comment: In your storyboard click the cell and create your segue to whatever `ViewController` you want to segue into.

Comment: I did link the tableViewCell to the detailViewController in my Storyboard. I just updated my questions with this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and hold "ctrl" from your `UITableViewCell` to your desired view controller. As segue type use push and give the segue an identifier. Then you can call `performSegue:segue` and check if your segue gets called by

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"your identifier"]) {
         YourViewController *yourVC = (YourViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
         // prepare your vc
      }
 }
```

You can also remove the check `cell==nil` as this is no longer necessary since iOS 6.

Comment: @cfisher have you already removed the cell==nil check? You can remove the whole if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare for segue is only called when perform segue is called either because of a connection you had in the storyboard or you called perform segue explicitly.

For invoking perform segue - 
Ctr+ drag from your uitableviewController to detailviewController. Assign the segue an identifier.

And in your custom class - 
for the method tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: - 
call the method performSegueWithIdentifier: and pass the identifier.
Also remember to deselect the cell.

At this point, the prepare for Segue will be called.

Comment: I do have a connection in my storyboard. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Did you try calling performSegueWithIdentifier: ?

Comment: I thought it wasn't necessary, after connecting the cell with the next VC in the storyboard.

Comment: Are you using a static cell or dynamic prototype? I believe this might create the difference.